# How can I ask about file formats on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I am looking for a reasonable architecture of my software.

One decision I have to take is what file format I use to describe a subpart of my system (connections and devices). The subpart should be compatible to a set of existing software ([MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), [Simulink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulink), etc.), but that domain (electrical engineering) is unknown to me.

How can I ask a question like that without it being an opinion poll?

I can not ask my question straight out, because I feel like the answer would map to one question and N possibly correct answers.

The question I am thinking of would go like this:

"I am looking for a way of describing electrical connections between hardware (power supplies, etc.) with a file format or a library that is widely used in electrical engineering and also an open and well documented standard."

I can not see how to ask this question on Stack Overflow.

How and where could I ask this question?

Comment: Ask it on a site other than SO.  Or chat, if you really want to.